# Does Karate supports Neo4j Database?

Tags: neo4j, karate

Want to know if *Karate supports Neo4j database*?. If yes, would like to have an ex. feature which will be helpful.

Comment: i have accepted the answer. Can you please tell me if Karate Supports Neo4j database validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate [supports any Java code](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) so that way indirectly you should be able to do anything you want.

Please look at this JDBC example which will get you started: [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature). You will need to write a little bit of Java code (one time only) so if you don't have that skill, please ask someone to help.

```
# use jdbc to validate
* def config = { username: 'sa', password: '', url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb', driverClassName: 'org.h2.Driver' }
* def DbUtils = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.demo.util.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtils(config)

# since the DbUtils returns a Java Map, it becomes normal JSON here !
# which means that you can use the full power of Karate's 'match' syntax
* def dogs = db.readRows('SELECT * FROM DOGS')
* match dogs contains { ID: '#(id)', NAME: 'Scooby' }
```