# Looking for a solution to use Karate framework in most parts of my end to end automation

Tags: karate

Here is the scenario:
1. Run couple of API tests before starting my Automation. 
2. User Signup though Application-A which is a mobile app. User will be asked to enter mobile number to receive OTP at the time of Sign up and will be asked to upload a photo too.
3. Submitted application will be stored in the Mongo Database.
4. Admin login through Application-B which is a Angular web based one and can review those information and approve them.
5. Run performance test may be separately or with other 1-4 steps.

I was asked to come up with a solution to approach end to end automation in a single test possibly. I can automate individual pieces using Karate or Rest Assured for API, Appium for Mobile app based, Selenium/Mongo DB integration for Mongo Database validation and finally Protractor for Angular web application testing. Also, i can do JMeter for Performance testing.

I wanted to understand what all and how much of my scenarios are possible with Karate framework and what is the best solution that this framework can offer.

Comment: You should really break down your goals into smaller pieces.  Your question is begging for an opinionated answer, not necessarily the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with Karate. Read the docs:

- API: https://github.com/intuit/karate
- Appium: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/743 (use 0.9.5.RC5, and contribute gaps if needed)
- Web: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core (use 0.9.5.RC5)
- Also see: https://hackernoon.com/the-world-needs-an-alternative-to-selenium-so-we-built-one-zrk3j3nyr
- Database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714248/143475

I suggest you do a PoC because you have asked a big, blanket question and only you can answer it for yourself. I also recommend not combining Mobile testing into the same single flow, because it may make things more complicated than necessary. You should have a separate test where the auth token is generated via an API (create a special end point for test if needed) and then you enter the mobile test.