# Cucumber/karate code to connect to bigquery, query and compare the result with existing values

Tags: automation, cucumber, karate, gherkin

I am trying to compare result of bigquery and compare it with existing values, but I am not able to connect to bigquery. Could you please help me in writing Cucumber/karate code to connect to bigquery, query and compare the result with existing values?

Comment: I mean connection is established but now need to query from the code to big query and get the result.

Comment: please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714248/143475